# turning Radius value long

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

This piece of code is supposed to draw a line representing the turning radius of an object using it's velocity and angular velocity. For some reason, though, the radius given is way longer that it's supposed to be:

```
AngularVel = m_Rigidbody.angularVelocity.y;
Vel = m_Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;
//Vel = transform.InverseTransformDirection(m_Rigidbody.velocity).z; same result
float radius = Vel / (AngularVel * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
Quaternion RadiusDirQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(m_Rigidbody.rotation.eulerAngles.y + 90, Vector3.up);
Vector3 radiusDir = RadiusDirQuat * Vector3.forward;
Debug.DrawRay(m_Rigidbody.position + Vector3.up, radiusDir * radius, new Color(1, 0, 0.5f, 1));
```

I'm using this article for reference: https://revisionmaths.com/advanced-level-maths-revision/mechanics/motion-circle

Comment: I think you want `AngularVel = m_Rigidbody.angularVelocity.magnitude`, no?

Comment: Maybe you forgot a 2*pi somewhere in float radius= ... line. Is the radius you get about 6.28 times the original? angularVelocity.y should give rotations per second which is (1/(2*pi)) times the angular velocity. If it has 2 turns per second than it is 4*pi radians per second.

Comment: @Quantic I replaced it with that, but got the same result.

Comment: According to [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/units-of-rigidbody-angularvelocity.7055/), Unity's angular velocity is already in radians per second, yet you are multiplying by `Mathf.Deg2Rad`, so just remove that and make the line read: `float radius = Vel / AngularVel`.

Comment: @Quantic thanks, that is correct. They really should put what unit it's measured in into the documentation page for angularVelocity.

Comment: @Quantic if you upgrade your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/units-of-rigidbody-angularvelocity.7055/), Unity's angular velocity is already in radians per second, yet you are multiplying by `Mathf.Deg2Rad`, so just remove that and make the line read: `float radius = Vel / AngularVel`.